# how to split a string in excel vba macros ignoring last portion

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell which contains path values like:

```
C:/Videos/New/VideoName.mp4
```

I wanted to take only the path from that cell

So I tried

```
elementArray = Split(Cells(4, 2), "/")
```

So that I can concatenate the strings inside that array everytime

But the array is still having the full path

i.e

```
elementArray[0]=C:/Videos/New/VideoName.mp4
```

How can ignore the file name and take the path alone?

Comment: Your sample and the code for the split are using forward slashes (e.g. Chr(47)). Typically, paths (local and network) use back-slashes (e.g. Chr(92)). URLs and URIs use forward slashes.

Comment: @Jeeped excellent observation ! :)
dont know how i missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion on whether you are using and/or require forward slashes (e.g. `/` or `Chr(47)`) or back-slashes (e.g. `\` or `Chr(92)`). Try something like this:

```
dim sPath as string, sFullPath as string
sFullPath = "C:/Videos/New/VideoName.mp4"   ' or C:\Videos\New\VideoName.mp4
if len(sFullPath) > len(replace(sFullPath, Chr(47), vbnullstring)) then
    sPath = replace(sFullPath, split(sFullPath, Chr(47))(ubound(split(sFullPath, Chr(47)))), vbnullstring)
    debug.print sPath & " with forward slashes"
elseif len(sFullPath) > len(replace(sFullPath, Chr(92), vbnullstring)) then
    sPath = replace(sFullPath, split(sFullPath, Chr(92))(ubound(split(sFullPath, Chr(92)))), vbnullstring)
    debug.print sPath & " with back-slashes"
else
    debug.print "unknown separator"
end if
```

Look to the VBE's Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) for the results.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any issue, I would use the `GetParentFolderName()` method of the `FileSystemObject`, accessible by adding the reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName("your path")
```

Or in late-binding, as suggested by @SOofWXLS (so you avoid the early-binding of the library into the project):

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
parentFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName("your path")
```

I think it's the easiest and most robust way of parsing the parent folder by the full path: you avoid complex string manipulations that might let some "less common" cases apart (e.g. a Mac's path won't be parsed by the "manual" methods).

Comment: P.s. among the cases managed by the built-in method, there's also the misuse of forward and backward slashes to separate paths. In my opinion always prefer a built-in if possible, they're not only quicker but especially they rely on the job of a team of developers that have definitely considered every possible case.

Comment: @mattero i am getting an error when using FileSystemObject
it says "user type not defined"

Comment: @vignesh from the VBE you need to go to Tools/References and then add the library Microsoft Scripting Runtime, the class is defined in there

Comment: Would it be worth showing the late-binding method too? As much as it saddens me I don't think many vba users use early binding at design time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `InStrRev()` function:

```
With Cells(4, 2)
    MsgBox Mid(.Value, 1, InStrRev(.Value, "\") - 1)
End With
```

Comment: I think using `InStrRev` is make more sense ;).

Answer (score 1):

Please, read [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) comment to the question.

I would suggest to use [StrReverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) functions instead of `Split`:

```
Dim s As String, f As String

s = "C:\Videos\New\VideoName.mp4"
f = StrReverse(s)
'FileName
'f = Left(f, InStr(1, f, "\") - 1)
'Path
f = Right(f, InStr(1, f, "\"))
f = StrReverse(f)
MsgBox f

'returns: VideoName.mp4 or path - read above comments
```